# React - this.state is empty in render when getInitialState is properly defined

Tags: javascript, user-interface, reactjs, flux

I'll try my best to explain the scenario, as making a fiddle of the smallest possible case might be hard. Essentially, I have a SPA using React-Router. I'm currently getting a strange behavior in specifically one version of Firefox (31.4esr).

I have two sidebar icons which trigger a change in routes, navigating to a new page. On occasion when I switch quickly between them, I'm getting an error that this.state.list is undefined(this is a list that I populate a dropdown with).

The issue is, upon debugging, console.log(this.state) is returning an empty object just before the call (that errors) to this.state.list happens in my render method. However, I have list defined in getInitialState (along with a bunch of other state variables) and so this.state definitely shouldn't be empty.

The only thing I could think of that would be causing this is if due to the quick switching there is some confusion with mounting/unmounting of components and my component still thinks it is mounted, so skips the getInitialState and goes ahead and tries to render. Either that or some bug in React-Router.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help!

Nick

P.S I should reiterate this also only occurs very rarely during quick switching, and normally the componentDidMount -> getInitialState -> render occurs as expected, so it is not simply an error in how my getInitialState is written etc.

Edit: Using React 0.13.3 and React router 0.13.3

Edit 2: Here is the stripped down version of the lifecycle methods, very basic.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return { list: listStore.getList("myList") || [] }
},

 render: function() {

var newList = [];
//this is the line that errors with this.state.list is undefined
this.state.list.forEach(function(listItem) {
    ...
}

return (
    <div>
        <OtherComponent newList={newList} />
    </div>
    )

};
```

When putting console.log in componentWillMount (just attaches store listeners), getInitialState, and render, I get output like this when the error occurs:

```
"Setting initial state"
"2,3" //This is this.state.list in componentWillMount
"2,3" //This is this.state.list in initial Render
Object { } //This is this.state the next time it gets called in render :S.
```

Comment: When are you debugging/logging the state? what does it say if you log it inside `componentWillMount` ?

Comment: [`getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) is called before `componentDidMount`. Both state and props are available before mounting (see `componentWillMount`).

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? At least the stripped down version of all the lifecycle methods you're using?

Comment: Too true... Which makes it even more perplexing the initial values of state aren't available when render is called.

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now but I will check and post find thing tomorrow!

Comment: Updated with some code!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use mixin like  this:

```
var state = {
 getInitialState: function() {
  return { list: listStore.getList("myList") || [] }
 }
}
var nameRouter = React.createClass({
  mixins : [state],
  // more content
})
```

this is because react-router ignore the getInitialState that was definite